# Edit Kafka Listener Spring App to Change Stage/Target

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I can leverage another teams functioning Kafka application/codebase to consume the same data/load it into our new staging table instead of theirs. They have many different kafka listener adapter .java files within a "Messages" folder that each consume different types of data.

Each kafka listener has many imports, a public class, try statement that actually inserts the data, etc. What do I need to edit for each kafka listener adapter.java file to change the stage/target table from the other teams to mine? I found I just need to change the "groupid" and "topic" variables + (Find file with this format to configure/add new groupid/id: spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=new-groupid spring.kafka.listener.id=new-id). This is how the two variables are used in the .java file:

```
   @KafkaListener(topics = "#{new java.util.HashMap(${dataflow.consumer.props.assets.crypto}).keySet()}", groupId = "${dataflow.consumer.assets.crypto.group}",containerFactory = "cryptoListenerContainerFactory", id = "${dataflow.consumer.assets.crypto.group}")
```

Each kafka listener adapter has a repository variable so i'm not sure. It seems the data is actually being inserted in this code block referring to "Repository":

```
   try {
        List<FundEntity> cryptoFilteredList = cryptoConsumerRecordList.stream()
                .filter(cryptoConsumerRecord -> recordIsNotFilterable(cryptoConsumerRecord, FundEntity.class))
                .map(ConsumerRecord::value)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (!cryptoFilteredList.isEmpty()) {

            this.Repository.storecryptoCollection(cryptoFilteredList, topic, firstOffset, partition, cryptoGroupId);

            kafkaDetailsSummary.setStatus(KafkaMessageSummary.KafkaStatus.PROCESSED);
            log.info(LogHelper.generateCryptoReconMessage(cryptoFilteredList), keyValue(KAFKA_DETAILS, kafkaDetailsSummary));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`spring.kafka.listener.id`: there is no such property, and `spring.kafka.consumer.group-id` is only used if there is no `groupId` property on the annotation.

Since they are using property placeholders in the annotation, you just need to set the `dataflow.consumer.assets.crypto.group` property to the value that you want.

Comment: This property is defined in the listener adapter public class through "    @Value("${dataflow.consumer.assets.crypto.group}")
    String assetCryptoGroupId;". How do I configure this property with the stage/target table I want to insert data into? Also, would it be easier to simply copy their codebase and change their repository that the data is being inserted into to my teams?

Comment: The value is simply using the same placeholder as the one in the annotation; the annotation doesn't use the field populated by the `@Value` it just gets the same value as it. I don't know what you mean by `stage/target table`; that has nothing to do with Kafka.

Comment: I am under the impression that this line is where data is actually inserted into the Repository "     if (!cryptoFilteredList.isEmpty()) {

            this.Repository.storecryptoCollection(cryptoFilteredList, topic, firstOffset, partition, cryptoGroupId)". The goal is to insert the same data into my teams Repository instead of theirs. Would it be easier to simply copy their codebase and change their "Repository" name from theirs to our new one?

Comment: Right but storing in a repo has nothing to do with the Kafka listener id or group id; I have no knowledge about repositories.